# Como llamar una funcion escalar de SQL Server en Visual Basic 2017?

Tags: vb.net

tengo una funcion scalar creada en SQL Server 2016, esta le paso tres parametros codigo del empleado, tipo movimiento, fecha de corte, realizo un calculo de totalizar salarios en con la fecha de corte, en SQL server pefecto me funciona al 100%, pero cuando la mando o trato de llamar en VB no me devuelve nada, estoy utilizando data set.

funcion :

```
SELECT dbo.obtenerSalariosLiq ('5488',  1,'2018-02-23')
```

Llamada

```
me.mtaobtenerSalariosLiq.fill(me.dsnomina.obtenerSalariosLiq ('5488',  1,'2018-02-23')
```

Lo llamo como un table adapter, si yo ingreso el codigo de esta funcion en tiempo de diseño se me cae el sistema ya que marca error.

Me pondrian orienta que tengo malo en la llamada a esta funcion y lo que necesitoy es que esta funcion me devuelva el valor que encontro.

Saludos

Comment: Que error te marca?

Comment: Buienas noches, el problema o error es que no me devuelve nada, tengo un LABEL que presentare el monto o valor, cuando lo agrego al dataset lo hago como que fuera un SP y la llamada es de esta manera: mlbmontovacacion.text = mdsliquida.mpxsalario.fill(1,1020,0,fcha1,fcha2). Si lo sigo paso a paso hace bien el calculo, pero no se como hacer para que me retorne el valor.

Comment: Patricio no se si la llamada la estoy haciendo mal o al agregarlo al dataset la forma en que lo agrego y llamo como que fuera un table adaptare. salidos

Comment: Buenas tardes, estimados buscando en la web encontre como hacer la llamada a las funciones escalar, es un post de MS, resolvi y mi problema es que la lamaba como SP donde no es, la funcion necesita de un SELECT.para ser llamada.

Comment: Estupendo, te sugiero que escribas una respuesta detallando la solución encontrada si entiendes que puede ser de utilidad para otros, sino puedes eliminar tu pregunta. Saludos.